# fetch database from web into android

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am trying to load my database from web server and logging in to my app .

I'm using [oum saokosal](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2rvGRbu0A83cWF5QktoVU9NMlU&usp=sharing) source code.

> LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

final String LOG = "LoginActivity";
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);   

    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();

    String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    postData.put("txtUsername", username);
    postData.put("txtPassword", password);

    PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(LoginActivity.this, postData,
            new AsyncResponse() {
                @Override
                public void processFinish(String s) {
                    Log.d(LOG, s);
                    if(s.contains("success")){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sucessfully Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    task1.execute("http://symphonyrecords.gigfa.com/customer/");
}
}
```

> connection.php

```
<?php
$servername = "my_database_servername"; //replace it with your database server name
$username = "my_database_usename";  //replace it with your database username
$password = "my_database_password";  //replace it with your database password
$dbname = "my_database_name";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

PostResponseAsyncTask

> MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
       Button button1;
       Button button3;
       int clickerId;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.button1 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1));
         this.button2 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
        this.button3 = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3));
        this.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
          public void onClick(View v) {
             String url = "http://10.0.3.2/client/post.php?format=json";
             PostResponseAsyncTask readTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, new AsyncResponse()
             {
              public void processFinish(String s) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, 1).show();
              }
            });
            readTask.execute(new String[] { url });
          }
        });
        this.button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          public void onClick(View v) {
             String url = "http://10.0.3.2/client/post.php";
            PostResponseAsyncTask readTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, new AsyncResponse()
            {
               public void processFinish(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, 1).show();
              }
             });
            readTask.execute(new String[] { url });
          }
         });
         this.button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
          public void onClick(View v)
           {
           String url = "http://10.0.3.2/client/post.php";

            PostResponseAsyncTask readTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, false, new AsyncResponse()
            {
              public void processFinish(String s)
             {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, 1).show();
               }
            });
            readTask.execute(new String[] { url });
           }
        });
       }
     }
```

> PostResponseAsyncTask.java

```
 package com.kosalgeek.genasync12;

 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLEncoder;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map.Entry;

 public class PostResponseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
 {
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   private AsyncResponse delegate;
  private Context context;
   private HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap();
   private String loadingMessage = "Loading...";
   private boolean showLoadingMessage = true;

   public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
    this.delegate = delegate;
     this.context = context;
   }

   public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, boolean showLoadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.context = context;
    this.showLoadingMessage = showLoadingMessage;
   }

   public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.delegate = delegate;
   }
   public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, boolean showLoadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.delegate = delegate;
     this.showLoadingMessage = showLoadingMessage;
   }

  public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, String loadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
     this.context = context;
    this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
    this.delegate = delegate;
   }

   public PostResponseAsyncTask(Context context, HashMap<String, String> postData, String loadingMessage, AsyncResponse delegate)
   {
     this.context = context;
     this.postData = postData;
     this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
     this.delegate = delegate;
   }
   protected void onPreExecute()
   {
     if (this.showLoadingMessage == true) {
       this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
       this.progressDialog.setMessage(this.loadingMessage);
       this.progressDialog.show();
    }

     super.onPreExecute();
   }

   protected String doInBackground(String[] urls)
   {
     String result = "";

     for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
    {
      result = invokePost(urls[i], this.postData);
     }

    return result;
  }

  private String invokePost(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams)
   {
     String response = "";
    try {
      URL url = new URL(requestURL);

       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
       conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setDoInput(true);
      conn.setDoOutput(true);

       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

       writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

      writer.flush();
       writer.close();
       os.close();
      int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

       if (responseCode == 200)
       {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         String line;
         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
          response = new StringBuilder().append(response).append(line).toString();
       }
       else
       {
         response = "";

         Log.i("PostResponseAsyncTask", new StringBuilder().append(responseCode).append("").toString());
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return response;
   }

   private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     boolean first = true;

     for (Map.Entry entry : params.entrySet()) {
      if (first)
        first = false;
      else {
        result.append("&");
      }
       result.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
     result.append("=");
       result.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
  }

   protected void onPostExecute(String result)
   {
     if ((this.showLoadingMessage == true) && 
(this.progressDialog.isShowing())) {
this.progressDialog.dismiss();
}

result = result.trim();

this.delegate.processFinish(result);
}

public String getLoadingMessage()
{
    return this.loadingMessage;
}

   public void setLoadingMessage(String loadingMessage) {
     this.loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
   }

  public HashMap<String, String> getPostData() {
    return this.postData;
  }

  public void setPostData(HashMap<String, String> postData) {
    this.postData = postData;
  }

   public Context getContext() {
    return this.context;
   }

   public AsyncResponse getDelegate() {
    return this.delegate;
  }
 }
```

(http://symphonyrecords.gigfa.com/customer)
`connection.php` file is in *customer* root folder in my host

I have created my username and password database in my cPanel , and it is working  just fine in browser but in app it gives me connection failed.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: When the app gives you "Connection failed" does mysqli_connect_error() give you any output?

Comment: I just realized that you may get "Connection failed" message from elsewhere in the app, try alerting the return variable 's' to get an idea of what is being returned, or check the log value.

Comment: Also, ensure that your app has the permission to access network resources